# Is $\sigma(X+Y) \subseteq \sigma (X,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,M,P)$ be a probability space,  $ X_{1} $ and $ X_2 $ be two random variavles, is it ture that $\sigma(X_1+X_2) \subseteq \sigma (X_1,X_2)$ ? How can we prove this?

Someone told me that this is a conclusion of Doob-dynkin's theorem.

**Doob-Dynkin's Theorem**: Lex $X=(X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$ be a $R^n$ random variable, and Y be a $R$-valued random variable, then Y is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(X)$ iff there exists a Borel measurable function f on $R^n$ such that $Y=f(X)$.

In this way, we can define $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$, then $Y=f(X)$, hence $Y$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(X)$ by Doob-dynkin's theorem.

But the question here is: why $\sigma(X)=\sigma(X_1,X_2)$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Do you know how $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(X_1, X_2)$ are defined? Can you show that each contains the other? If not, where do you get stuck?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen $\sigma (X) := \sigma\{X^{-1}(A),A\in {B_{R^n}}\}$, and $\sigma(X_1,X_2)=\sigma(\sigma (X_1)\bigcup \sigma(X_2))$,  but I don't know how to verify that they're identity.

Comment: OK. If $\mathcal F_1, \mathcal F_2$ are $\sigma$-algebras and $\mathcal F_i$ is generated by the family $\mathcal A_i$, then to show that $\mathcal F_1 \subseteq \mathcal F_2$, you need to show that $\mathcal A_1 \subseteq \mathcal F_2$. Does that get you any further?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, I know this. Actually, I've been thinking about such a thing: if $B_{R^n}$ is generated by $\mathcal{F} $, is "$\sigma(X)=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(A), A \in \mathcal{F} \})$" true?

Answer (score 1):

We can check that
$$\sigma(X)=\text{the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ such that $X$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable}.$$
Indeed, if $X$ is measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ then $\mathscr{A}$ must contain all sets of the form $X^{-1}(A)$, where $A$ is a Borel set. Since those sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, the assertion follows. In the same spirit, we can also show that
$$\sigma(X,Y)=\text{the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathscr{B}$-measurable}. $$
In particular, $X+Y$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X,Y)$ (by Doob-Dynkin's theorem); hence $\sigma(X+Y)\subset\sigma(X,Y)$.

(Edited) As for your question, set $Z=(X,Y)$. Then $Z$ is measurable if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are measurable. The forward implication follows from
$$X=\pi_1\circ Z\qquad\text{and}\qquad Y=\pi_2\circ Z, $$
where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are coordinate functionals; $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$. Since these functionals are continuous, the measurability of $Z$ implies those of $X$ and $Y$. Conversely, note that if $A$, $B$ are Borel sets then
$$ Z^{-1}(A\times B)=X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(B). $$
Thus if $X$ and $Y$ are measurable, $Z^{-1}(A\times B)$ is also a measurable set. But sets of the form $A\times B$ generate the Borel sets of the product space, so it follows that $Z$ is measurable.

Comment: OP's question is: why $\sigma((X,Y))=\sigma(X,Y)$?

Comment: @Snoop Yes, that is my question

Comment: I edited my answer. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @MintChocolate Thanks for your answer, I know what to do. Actually, both of $X$ and $Y$ are $(\sigma(X,Y), B_R)$-measurable, hence we can limit our discussion of this problem to $(\Omega,\sigma(X,Y),P)$, and by the disscussion of the second part of your answer, $Z$ is $(\sigma(X,Y), B_{R^n})$-measurable, which means that $\sigma(Z)\subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$. Do the same thing in the opppsite direction,we can get that $\sigma(Z)\supseteq \sigma(X,Y)$, right?

Comment: Yes. The measurability of $Z$ and the measurability of $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent, so the corresponding $\sigma$-algebras must be the same.

Comment: @MintChocolate I see, Thank you very much!